# How to get the doc id from this stream in flutter firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to retrieve the doc id inside the stream builder and i am using query snapshot

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the code in texts as suggested by Frank? Also please visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a good question in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 2):

you can get documentId inside Listview.builder for each document like this:

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].id
```